# Procedure call in ORDS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

When I call the procedure through PL/SQL , it works fine but when i call the same through ORDS with same input , it throws the below error. Please correct me.

SQL Error Code: 6550, Error Message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ‘BALA_payc_details’ ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PL/SQL:

Below is complete code

---

```sql
BEGIN
ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
  p_enabled => TRUE,
  p_schema => ‘TestAPI’,
  p_url_mapping_type => ‘BASE_PATH’,
  p_url_mapping_pattern => ‘TestAPI’,
  p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);

ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_base_path => ‘/pay/’,
  p_items_per_page => 0,
  p_status => ‘PUBLISHED’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_priority => 0,
  p_etag_type => ‘HASH’, 
  p_etag_query => NULL,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_source_type => ‘plsql/block’,
  p_items_per_page => 5,
  p_mimes_allowed => ”,
  p_comments => NULL,
  p_source =>
  ‘begin
  TCTD.PKG_BALA.BALA_payc_details(
  finp_type => :nptype,
  finp_value => :npvalue,
  fIsPaycard => :card,
  p_verrcode => :code,
  p_verrdesc => :description,
  v_refcur => :v_refcur);
  end;’
);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘nptype’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘nptype’,
  p_source_type => ‘HEADER’,
  p_param_type => ‘STRING’,
  p_access_method => ‘IN’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘npvalue’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘npvalue’,
  p_source_type => ‘HEADER’,
  p_param_type => ‘STRING’,
  p_access_method => ‘IN’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘card’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘card’,
  p_source_type => ‘HEADER’,
  p_param_type => ‘STRING’,
  p_access_method => ‘IN’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘code’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘code’,
  p_source_type => ‘RESPONSE’,
  p_param_type => ‘INT’,
  p_access_method => ‘OUT’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘description’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘description’,
  p_source_type => ‘RESPONSE’,
  p_param_type => ‘STRING’,
  p_access_method => ‘OUT’,
  p_comments => NULL);

ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_name => ‘v_refcur’,
  p_bind_variable_name => ‘v_refcur’,
  p_source_type => ‘RESPONSE’,
  p_param_type => ‘RESULTSET’,
  p_access_method => ‘OUT’,
  p_comments => NULL);

COMMIT;
END;
```

---

Postman JSON Input…

```json
{
“nptype” : “S”,
“nptypevalue” : “23456”,
“card” : “Y”
}
```

This throws error ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ‘ ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ‘BALA_payc_details’’

---

2.. When I call the same procedure with below input in PL/SQL , it is working fine.

```sql
DECLARE
verrcode Number(10);
verrdesc varchar2(100);
v_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
TCTD.PKG_BALA.BALA_payc_details (‘S’,’23456′,’Y’,verrcode,verrdesc,v_refcur);
END;
```

---

Please let me know what I need to change in ORDS call?

Comment: The json payload example has 3 arguments, the working pl/sql example has 5 arguments. What happens if you execute the example in pl/sql like this ```TCTD.PKG_BALA.BALA_payc_details (‘S’,’23456′,’Y’);```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are executing successfully in pl/sql is NOT the same code that is in the handler. If you change the hander to the following they both are the same. Note that I copied this code from your question and the single quotes will not be valid when you copy this code back into your ide. Replace the quotes with proper single quotes.

```
ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
  p_module_name => ‘pay’,
  p_pattern => ‘/inquiry’,
  p_method => ‘POST’,
  p_source_type => ‘plsql/block’,
  p_items_per_page => 5,
  p_mimes_allowed => ”,
  p_comments => NULL,
  p_source =>
  ‘DECLARE
verrcode Number(10);
verrdesc varchar2(100);
v_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  TCTD.PKG_BALA.BALA_payc_details(
  finp_type => :nptype,
  finp_value => :npvalue,
  fIsPaycard => :card,
  p_verrcode => verrcode,
  p_verrdesc => verrdesc,
  v_refcur => v_refcur);
  end;’
);
```

But... with a ref cursor as bind variable that is probably never going to work. A ref cursor is an internal oracle type - how do you plan to pass that as part of a json payload ?